# Reactjs, update all child components from sibling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, components

I do sorting on reactjs, I can’t understand how to redraw all child components so that only one selected remains active, I can update the current one, but the others do not change. Here is the code for an example. Can anyone help / explain how to do it right?

nodejs, webpack, last reactjs

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Parent from "./Parent";

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Parent />
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Parent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            popularity: {"sorting": "desc", "active": true},
            rating: {"sorting": "desc", "active": false},
            reviews_count: {"sorting": "desc", "active": false},
        };
    }

    updateFilters = () => {
        // ??
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child type="popularity" sorting={this.state.popularity.sorting} active={this.state.popularity.active} updateFilters={this.updateFilters} />
                <Child type="rating" sorting={this.state.rating.sorting} active={this.state.rating.active} updateFilters={this.updateFilters} />
                <Child type="reviews_count" sorting={this.state.reviews_count.sorting} active={this.state.reviews_count.active} updateFilters={this.updateFilters} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Parent;
```

Child.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        this.props.updateFilters();
    };

    render() {
        let activeStr = "";

        if (this.props.active) {
            activeStr = "active"
        } else {
            activeStr = "inactive";
        }

        return(
            <div onClick={() => this.handleClick}>
                {this.props.type} {activeStr} {this.props.sorting}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to set the active flag for a clicked Type to true and also set all the other types to false.

---

`<div onClick={() => this.handleClick}>` this isn't correct, as you aren't invoking the function. This could be corrected to:

```
<div onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>
```

Then you can update handleClick to pass the Type:

```
handleClick = () => {
  this.props.updateFilters(this.props.type);
};
```

**OR**

You could ignore that handleClick and call the prop function:

```
<div onClick={() => this.props.updateFilters(this.props.type)}>
```

Once you have passed the Type back into the `updateFilters`, we can simply iterate over the previous State Properties, setting all Types' Active Flag to false. However, if the Key matches the Type which was clicked, we set it to true.

```
  updateFilters = type => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return Object.keys(prevState).reduce(
        (result, key) => ({
          ...result,
          [key]: { ...prevState[key], active: key === type }
        }),
        {}
      );
    });
  };
```

---

Your Child component could be heavily refactored into a Pure Functional Component, making it a lot simpler:

```
const Child = ({ type, active, updateFilters, sorting }) => (
  <div onClick={() => updateFilters(type)}>
    {type} {active ? "active" : "inactive"} {sorting}
  </div>
);
```

Work solution:
https://codesandbox.io/s/4j83nry569